# Помогите реализовать движение карты (камера) в зависимости от расположения персонажа | PyGame

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр, gui, pygame

Код на *python*, библиотека *PyGame*
Помогите реализовать движение карты (камера)  в зависимости от расположения персонажа (хотя бы словами)
Начал изучение *PyGame*, не понимаю как реализовать камеру
Размер карты - 2560 на 1280; Размер окна - 1280 на 720
Персонаж должен из правого нижнего угла карты перейти в левый верхний, и, сделать так, чтобы карта двигалась на 50 пикселей, когда персонаж у края окна
Повторяюсь - *Пожалуйста, объясните хотя бы словами, очень нужно, заранее спасибо*
Картинки - https://yadi.sk/d/XkhfZTg79MBlow
Код:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))

pygame.display.set_caption('Рыцарь')
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("textures/icon.bmp"))

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_right.png'),
             pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_right2.png'),
             pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_right3.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_left.png'),
            pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_left2.png'),
            pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_left3.png')]
walkUp = [pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_up.png'),
          pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_up2.png'),
          pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_up3.png')]
walkDown = [pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_down.png'),
            pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_stand.png'),
            pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_down2.png')]

background = pygame.image.load('textures/first_karta.png')
playerStand = pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_stand.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x = 1255
y = 675
width = 20
height = 40
speed = 5

right, left, up, down, animCount = False, False, False, False, 0


def drawingWindow():
    global animCount
    win.blit(background, (0, 0))

    if animCount + 1 >= 60:
        animCount = 0

    if left:
        win.blit(walkLeft[animCount % 3], (x, y))
        animCount += 1
    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight[animCount % 3], (x, y))
        animCount += 1
    elif up:
        win.blit(walkUp[animCount % 3], (x, y))
        animCount += 1
    elif down:
        win.blit(walkDown[animCount % 3], (x, y))
        animCount += 1
    else:
        win.blit(playerStand, (x, y))

    pygame.display.update()


run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 5:
        x -= speed
        right, left, up, down = False, True, False, False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 1280 - width - 5:
        x += speed
        right, left, up, down = True, False, False, False
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > 5:
        y -= speed
        right, left, up, down = False, False, True, False
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 720 - height - 5:
        y += speed
        right, left, up, down = False, False, False, True
    else:
        right, left, up, down, animCount = False, False, False, False, 0

    drawingWindow()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 3):

Я не совсем понял что ты именно хотел, но для того чтобы реализовать камеру я советую создать класс cam, содержащий в себе переменную rect. В главном игровом цикле ты должен двигать первые 2 элемента rect у камеры и у игркоа (x, и y) на вектор, равный вектору персонажа, а затем отрисовывать задний фон на отрицательных координатах камеры. (если игрок идёт вверх, двигать rect камеры вверх, если влево, двигать влево). Вот небольшой пример этой камеры

```py
import pygame as pg
import sys
import random as rnd

pg.init()
win = pg.display.set_mode((500, 500))
background = pg.image.load("background.png").convert()
##  Рекомендую использовать .convert(), иначе будет сильно лагать

class cam:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.rect = pg.Rect(x, y, 500, 500)

    def move(self, vector):
        self.rect[0] += vector[0]
        self.rect[1] += vector[1]

class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.rect = pg.Rect(x, y, 10, 10)

    def move(self, vector):
        self.rect[0] += vector[0]
        self.rect[1] += vector[1]

    def draw(self):
        ##  Игрок на самом окне не двигается, двигается мир вокруг него
        pg.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), (240, 240, 10, 10))

class object:
    ##  Это какой-нибудь объект, отличный игрока (к примеру враг или дерево)
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.rect = pg.Rect(x, y, width, height)

    def draw(self):
        ##  Чтобы отрисовка соответствовала позиции объекта его нужно отрисовывать
        ##  на self.rect[0]-camera.rect[0], self.rect[1]-camera.rect[1]
        pg.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (self.rect[0] - camera.rect[0], self.rect[1] - camera.rect[1], self.rect[2], self.rect[3]), 2)

##  P.S. я указывал переменные rect для того, чтобы можно было проверять коллизию между
##  объектами. К примеру: для увеличения производительности, в этой программе отрисовываются лишь те
##  объекты, которые попадают в камеру. (Загугли pg.Rect.colliderect для большего)

player = Player(0, 0)
camera = cam(0, 0)

objects = [object(250, 250, 30, 10)]

while  1:

    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                objects.append(object(rnd.randint(0, 400), rnd.randint(0, 400), rnd.randint(5, 15), rnd.randint(5, 15)))

    vector = [0, 0]

    kpressed = pg.key.get_pressed()
    if kpressed[pg.K_UP]:
        vector[1] -= 3
    elif kpressed[pg.K_DOWN]:
        vector[1] += 3

    if kpressed[pg.K_LEFT]:
        vector[0] -= 3
    elif kpressed[pg.K_RIGHT]:
        vector[0] += 3

    ##  Если игрок ходил
    if vector != [0, 0]:
        player.move(vector)
        camera.move(vector)

    win.fill((255, 255, 255))
    win.blit(background, (-camera.rect[0], -camera.rect[1]))
    player.draw()

    ##  ДЛЯ ПРО
    ##  отрисовка других объектов
    for obj in objects:
        ##  Если объект на экране, отрисовать его
        if obj.rect.colliderect(camera.rect):
            obj.draw()

    pg.display.flip() ##    = pg.display.update()
    pg.time.wait(30)
```

Изображение можно использовать любое, главное поместить рядом с прогой и переименовать в background.png
Нажав на space можно добавить объект (подробнее в коде)

P. S. Очень советую изучить ООП в питоне т.к. без него игры делать почти невозможно